# Query to fill Gridview with rows that contain only numeric values is not giving me the result that I want

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, excel, gridview

I uploaded an Excel file, and I'm sorting the rows into 2 tables, one that has Valid and acceptable data, the other containing data that needs to be edited in order to be validated. 
I have 3 columns: Name, Email, and Mobile
I'm having trouble querying the rows with valid Mobile values (numeric values, no letters allowed)

(SCROLL DOWN UNTIL YOU REACH "MY PROBLEM IS IN THE BELOW QUERY"
Here's my code:

```js
 protected void UploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = string.Empty;
        if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {

            try
            {
                string[] allowFile = { ".xls", ".xlsx" };
                string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                bool isVaidFile = allowFile.Contains(fileExt);
                if (!isVaidFile)
                {
                    MessageLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    MessageLbl.Text = "Must be an Excel file";
                }
                else
                {
                    int fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    if (fileSize <= 1048576)
                    {
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName));
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadExcel/") + filename);
                        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadExcel/") + filename;
                        OleDbConnection con = null;
                        if (fileExt == ".xls")
                        {
                            con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";");
                        }
                        else if (fileExt == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";");
                        }
                        con.Open();
                        DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        string getExcelSheetName = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                        OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = 
                            new OleDbCommand(@" SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"]", con);
                        OleDbCommand EditExcelCommand = 
                            new OleDbCommand(@" SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] where Email not like '%@%.com' or Email is null or Name is null or Mobile is null or Mobile not like '^[[:digit:]]+$'", con);
                        //
                        //
                        // MY PROBLEM IS IN THE BELOW QUERY
                        //
                        //
                        OleDbCommand ValidExcelCommand =
                            new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] where ((Email like '%@%.com') and (Name is not null) and (Mobile like '^[[:digit:]]+$'))", con);
                        OleDbDataAdapter EditAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(EditExcelCommand);
                        OleDbDataAdapter ValidAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ValidExcelCommand);
                        OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);
                        DataSet ExcelDataSet = new DataSet();
                        DataSet EditDataSet = new DataSet();
                        DataSet ValidDataset = new DataSet();
                        EditAdapter.Fill(EditDataSet);
                        ValidAdapter.Fill(ValidDataset);
                        ExcelAdapter.Fill(ExcelDataSet);
                        con.Close();
                        GridView5.DataSource = ValidDataset;
                        GridView4.DataSource = EditDataSet;
                        GridView3.DataSource = ExcelDataSet;
                        GridView3.DataBind();
                        GridView4.DataBind();
                        GridView5.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageLbl.Text = "Attachment file size should not be greater than 1 MB";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageLbl.Text = "Error occurred while uploading file. " + ex.Message;
            }
        
        }
        else
        {
            MessageLbl.Text = "";
        }
       
        
    }
```

The image contains the results I'm getting

[GRIDVIEW RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HcFp.png)

My question is why is my ValidTable remaining empty? is something wrong with my query statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my query statement to the following and it worked

```js
string ValidExcelCommandText = @"SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] where ((Email like '%@_%.com') and (Name is not null) and not ( ISNUMERIC(Mobile) = 0))";
```

Comment: Well that's what I told you!I said you need to take the SELECT statement that is being generated and run it in SQL and if it doesn't return any results then fix your SQL query.Please mark my answer as correct because my answer helped you identify the problem and it's the right thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks valid, I suspect there might be a problem with your select statement.Create a simple string variable and set it equal to the command below:

```
   string validExcelCommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] where ((Email like '%@%.com') and (Name is not null) and (Mobile like '^[[:digit:]]+$'))";
```

Place a break point on this line and run your application, take the value of `validExcelCommandText` and run the query in SQL Server Management Studio.If it doesn't return any results then fix your SQL query if it does then make sure there is no logic that hides your `GridView` control on the page or check the bindings in the code behind.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, the query is not returning any search results at all. Although it is working properly for the EditTable query.
Even when I'm only querying for entries with just numbers I'm still getting an empty Query result:
string ValidExcelCommandText = @"SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] where ((Mobile like '^[[:digit:]]+$'))";
returns empty query

Comment: Please try what I have suggested

Comment: I have but still no result however I found a different way I'm about to  post it thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean no results?Did you take the SQL statement which is contained in the validExcelCommandText variable?Did you run it in SQL Server Management studio and what were the results?

Comment: Yes I did even in SQL Server Management same thing was happening I was getting an empty table which is very weird
I ended up using the ISNUMERI(Mobile)=0 for my query

Comment: Just because you asked so nicely :)